# List All Users On Mapped Drive CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a network drive and I was wondering how I could list all users on it.
I've tried to do the following:

```
pushd Z:
net user
```

With Z being the mapped drive, but it just lists users on my PC, rather than users on the network drive.

I don't know if "Users" is the correct term for this, here is what I'm talking about:

If you go to change a file's permissions, it gives you a screen to search users. These are the users I am talking about.
[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear, please provide more information.

Comment: Tried to clarify, please check again.

Comment: Sorry, but you're nowhere nearer to clarifying; what do you mean by users on the network drive?

Comment: Do you mean users who are currently connected to the share? Do you mean all users who have permission to connect to the share?

Comment: I think all users with permission to connect to the share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need admin rights on the remote system to pull this kind of data.  So long as that's not an issue, WMI can enumerate the permissions configured on a share, or on all the shares.

Those permissions are listed in SDDL format, so some translation will be needed from SID -> UserId, as well as what access is assigned.  That said, something is far better than nothing.  :-)

Just change "%computername%" to the name of your target, and you're ready to go.

-- CMD TO SHOW ALL POSSIBLE DATA WMIC CAN ENUMERATE:

```
wmic /node:"%computername%" /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\smb path MSFT_SmbShare get __CLASS,*
```

-- CMD USED TO PRODUCE OUTPUT BELOW:

```
wmic /node:"%computername%" /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\smb path MSFT_SmbShare get name,path,securitydescriptor,volume
```

-- OUTPUT:

```
Name     Path                               SecurityDescriptor                                                                                                                                                     Volume           
IPC$                                        O:SYG:SYD:(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;BO)(A;;GA;;;IU)                                                                                                                                                   
print$   C:\Windows\system32\spool\drivers  O:BAG:BAD:(A;;0x1200a9;;;WD)(A;;FA;;;BA)                                                                                                                               \\?\Volume{075d9bbd-0605-11e4-8250-806e6f6e6963}\
ToolBox  C:\ToolBox                         O:BAG:S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-513D:(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-1002)(A;;FA;;;WD)(A;;FA;;;S-1-5-21-27797481-235746463-772742770-1007)  \\?\Volume{075d9bbd-0605-11e4-8250-806e6f6e6963}\
```